# Send object instead of proxy via Distributed Objects

Tags: cocoa, proxy, distributed-objects

I can't solve next problem: I have 2 applications which talk to each other using Distributed Objects. Suppose application A call `- (void)updateState:(State *)state` method  from application B. 
`@interface State : NSObject <NSCopying, NSCoding>...` 
When `updateState:` method called in B app I have `NSDistantObject` representing sended object instead of `State` object. In [Friday Q&A](https://mikeash.com/pyblog/friday-qa-2009-02-20-the-good-and-bad-of-distributed-objects.html) I found that if object conforms to `NSCoding` protocol the object should be 'sended' instead of proxy, but, I still receive a proxy. I don't find any info about it in Apple Documentation. Maybe someone does know how can I send object instead of proxy and how Distributed Objects system decide when serialize and send an object and when a proxy?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found it! Also, you should implement `- (id)replacementObjectForPortCoder:(NSPortCoder *)coder` in object, which you want to pass through. More about this method you can read in [Apple documentation](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/DistrObjects/Tasks/substitutions.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/20000769-BBCJJDGI).
Mystical `isBycopy` and `isByref` of `NSPortCoder`, which Apple refs to [documentation](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/DistrObjects/DistrObjects.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/10000102-SW1), but in last is no info, determined by `bycopy` and `byref` method parameters keywords. More about this keywords you can read [here](http://objc.toodarkpark.net/moreobjc.html).